# How to search NetSuite location by location name list via SOAP

Tags: soap, netsuite

I'm trying to search NetSuite location  records by location name list via SOAP. According to the [Location schema documentation](http://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_2/script/record/location.html), the search column 'name' is with the 'text' type but not list, so I try to use the 'getList' method instead.

According to the message document, the getList schema is as below:

```
<complexType name="GetListRequest">
    <sequence>
        <element name="baseRef" type="platformCore:BaseRef" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

and the BaseRef document is as below:

```
<complexType name="BaseRef" abstract="true">
    <sequence>
        <element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <!-- record name -->
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

So I built the SOAP body:

```
<soap:Body>
    <platformMsgs:getList xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"  xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_2016_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"    xmlns:listAcct="urn:accounting_2016_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <platformMsgs:baseRef xsi:type="platformCore:RecordRef" type="location">
            <platformCore:name>some name</platformCore:name>
        </platformMsgs:baseRef>
    </platformMsgs:getList>
</soap:Body>
```

And got the error msg:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <getListResponse xmlns="urn:messages_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
        <readResponseList>
            <platformCore:status isSuccess="true" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
            <readResponse>
                <platformCore:status isSuccess="false" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2016_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                    <platformCore:statusDetail type="ERROR">
                        <platformCore:code>INVALID_KEY_OR_REF</platformCore:code>
                        <platformCore:message>The specified key is invalid.</platformCore:message>
                    </platformCore:statusDetail>
                </platformCore:status>
            </readResponse>
        </readResponseList>
    </getListResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I think I must have misunderstand something on the use of the getList method, but I can't find the answer by search Google or StackOverflow, any information and suggestion would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance! And sorry for the images can't be shown as embedded because of my low reputation score.

Comment: Try putting in the code directly as your schema above - it's easier for people than pasting in or linking to images

Comment: @Umaomamaomao Hi, Umaomamaomao, I have tried it before, by using the code, the editor always say the xml format indent is not right, and I can't submit this question. I think any further suggestion for the code paste action would be helpful to me, thank you!

Comment: @Umaomamaomao Hi, Umaomamaomao, as you suggested, I have changed the photo to the code, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Good work. For next time, it's usually best to do this at the time you post your question initially - as an old question won't attract much attention, and a new one with links to images of code won't either.

Comment: @Umaomamaomao Thanks for your suggestion again. Could you help have a look on this question?

Comment: Sorry I don't have the expertise on this question, just trying to help you get better answers from people who do

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter in a `getList` command. Instead, you'll need to run a `LocationSearchBasic` ([here's the documentation](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2019_1/schema/search/locationsearchbasic.html?mode=package)) which will allow you to filter by name.

Here's an example of how to generate this search using the [NetSuite ruby gem](http://github.com/netSweet/netsuite):

```
search = NetSuite::Records::Location.search(
  basic: [
    {
      field: 'name',
      operator: 'is',
      value: 'some name'
    }
  ]
)

search.results
```